# Are there any methods that allow an archer to deal AoE attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Are there any feats or spells available in Pathfinder that allow a bow-wielding character to use their arrows to hit more than a single target in a single square? Preferably something that is useful until at least mid-game (~level 10).

Comment: 'yes'.  Unless your question is really niche or founded on a lot of research, 'are there any' is almost always gonna be too broad.  Can you give us some criteria to determine the best answer by?